# php extension made from SWIG not loading

Tags: php, c++, swig

I am making a shared library that I can use in PHP with the help of SWIG. The library is based on some C++ code that also calls fortran functions. Yah its crazy. The first thing I did was to create a shared library of the FORTRAN subroutines. I did this using cmake, which produced the file libmasterfile.so. The next part was to compile the c++ code into objects:

```
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"Chunk.d" -MT"Chunk.d" -o "Chunk.o" "../Chunk.cpp"
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"MasterFile.d" -MT"MasterFile.d" -o "MasterFile.o" "../MasterFile.cpp"
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"Package.d" -MT"Package.d" -o "Package.o" "../Package.cpp"
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"Queue.d" -MT"Queue.d" -o "Queue.o" "../Queue.cpp"
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"Variable.d" -MT"Variable.d" -o "Variable.o" "../Variable.cpp"
```

after that I wrote the interface file for the swig shared library:

```
%module prq
%{
#include "Chunk.h"
#include "ConcreteQueue.h"
#include "ConcreteRequest.h"
#include "MasterFile.h"
#include "Package.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "QueueFactory.h"
#include "Request.h"
#include "RequestFactory.h"
#include "Variable.h"
using namespace PRQ;
%}
%include "../Chunk.h"
%include "../ConcreteQueue.h"
%include "../ConcreteRequest.h"
%include "../MasterFile.h"
%include "../Package.h"
%include "../Queue.h"
%include "../QueueFactory.h"
%include "../Request.h"
%include "../RequestFactory.h"
%include "../Variable.h"
```

next is to swig it, then compile the swig with g++, and finally link everything together:

```
swig -c++ -php5 prq.i
g++ `php-config --includes` -std=c++11 -O2 -fPIC -c prq_wrap.cpp
g++ -shared Chunk.o MasterFile.o Package.o Queue.o Variable.o prq_wrap.o -o prq.so -L/home/jlahowetz2/development/package-request-queue/ -lmasterfile -lgfortran
```

All of this seems to compile correctly. I added the extension via php.ini and restarted apache2. The php error logs show no errors and all seems well when I got to see if the extension is loaded i get nothing:

```
php -m | grep prq
```

and using php script from the command line I get the same, it this case a No:

```
<?php 
echo "START\n";
if (extension_loaded("prq")) echo "YES\n";
else echo "NO\n";
echo "END\n";
?>
```

So where do i go now? Not sure why php is not loading the extension. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the extension directive from php.ini and instead did as follows:

1. cd /etc/php5/mods-available
2. sudo vim prq.ini
3. added the extension directive to the above file
4. sudo php5enmod prq
   And that loaded the extension.